# What can be the reason to get rejected with this message by AppStore for my ios application?

Tags: ios, app-store

> This app is verified to contain mangled selectors such as `[h8uVi5M7
>   h2KfZCbl]` and `[n5SkqdHO i4g0IDLa:]`. This is the exclusive cause of
>   this app's continued 2.3.1 rejection. We recommend that you use the
>   "nm" tool or the command line tools "strings" or "otool -ov" to find
>   the entities that are causing this rejection. It would be appropriate
>   to remove all obfuscation from this app or to explain in detail the
>   reason for its inclusion.

By the way, i do not use any extra obfuscation tool.

Comment: Your app appears to have obfuscated function names.  This is often used to try and hide the use of private APIs. If you aren't using an obfuscation tool, how are you generating your app?  Presumably not Swift or Objective C.